# How can I insert image by POI library correctly in Android? When I insert the image, EXCEL can't read file. "Excel found unreadable content in..."

Tags: android, image, apache-poi, xlsx

I would like to insert some image as well as text.
When I insert image (first code), EXCEL in PC can't read the file.
EXCEL says "Excel found unreadable content in..."

But, when I skip the code about inserting the image (just add text on EXCEL)
EXCEL can read the file well (second code)

How can I correct my code?

I worked by Android Studio 3.2.1 and Galaxy S6

//1st code (insert text and image)

```
package com.example.yonghwan.d20xlsservicesave1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Picture;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean isPermissionAllowed = isNotiPermissionAllowed();
        if(!isPermissionAllowed) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
        String path = storageDir + "/Test5.xlsx";
        File xlsFile = new File(path);


        try {
            storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Noti";
            path = storageDir + "/EXTRA.jpg";
            File iconFile = new File(path);
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(iconFile);
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(xlsFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int rowNumber = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            int pictureIndex = workbook.addPicture(bytes, XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
            inputStream.close();

            XSSFCreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber+1);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue("Image test : " + String.valueOf(rowNumber));
            anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();
            anchor.setCol1(0);
            anchor.setCol2(1);
            anchor.setRow1(rowNumber+1);
            anchor.setRow2(rowNumber+2);

            anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);

            Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsFile);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to save File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    private boolean isNotiPermissionAllowed() {
        Set<String> notiListenerSet = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this);
        String myPackageName = getPackageName();

        for(String packageName : notiListenerSet) {
            if(packageName == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if(packageName.equals(myPackageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

//2nd code (insert text only)

```
package com.example.yonghwan.d20xlsservicesave1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Picture;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean isPermissionAllowed = isNotiPermissionAllowed();
        if(!isPermissionAllowed) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        String storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
        String path = storageDir + "/Test5.xlsx";
        File xlsFile = new File(path);


        try {
            storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Noti";
            path = storageDir + "/EXTRA.jpg";
            File iconFile = new File(path);
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(iconFile);
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(xlsFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int rowNumber = sheet.getLastRowNum();

//            int pictureIndex = workbook.addPicture(bytes, XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
//            inputStream.close();

//            XSSFCreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
//            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
//            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber+1);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue("Image test : " + String.valueOf(rowNumber));
//            anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();
//            anchor.setCol1(0);
//            anchor.setCol2(1);
//            anchor.setRow1(rowNumber+1);
//            anchor.setRow2(rowNumber+2);

//            anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);

//            Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsFile);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to save File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    private boolean isNotiPermissionAllowed() {
        Set<String> notiListenerSet = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this);
        String myPackageName = getPackageName();

        for(String packageName : notiListenerSet) {
            if(packageName == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if(packageName.equals(myPackageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Cannot test using `android`. But what I would not do is creating the `anchor` again using `anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();`. You have it already created using `XSSFClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();` and this is the correct way. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images. So try without `anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
You're right.
But, although I remove the code "anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor();", EXCEL can't read the xlsx file.

Comment: Then this will be a special `android` related problem. The `android` implementation of `Java` `JRE` differs from the default `JRE`s. And there aer multiple issues with `apache poi` using `android`. Hint: Do tagging `android` too to attract `android` experts to your question.

Comment: I'll. Thank you for your comment.
Please help this issue.